# Port 8013 unavailable installing the Data Hub Central warfile in MarkLogic running in a docker container

Tags: docker, marklogic, central

My docker configuration needs to map ports for external access, but when trying to install the data hub central war file, `mlDeploy` and `mlRedeploy` encounter problems, that the ports are unavailable:

```
Task :mlDeployApp
Creating custom rewriters for staging and job app servers
Loading REST options for staging server
Initializing ExecutorService
Loading default query options from file default.xml
Shutting down ExecutorService
Loading REST options for jobs server
Initializing ExecutorService
Loading traces query options from file traces.xml
Shutting down ExecutorService

Writing traces query options to MarkLogic; port: 8013
Error occurred while loading modules; host: localhost; port: 8013;
 cause: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8013
```

...

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mlDeployApp'.

> Error occurred while loading REST modules: Error occurred while loading modules; host: localhost; port: 8013; cause: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8013

**Docker file contents**

FROM store/marklogicdb/marklogic-server:10.0-7-dev-centos
WORKDIR /tmp
EXPOSE 7997-8040
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 9000
CMD /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start && tail -f /dev/null

**Original docker run command:**

docker run -d --name=marklogic10.0-7_local -p 7997-8040:7997-8040 -p 8080:8080 -p 9000:9000 marklogic-initial-install:10.0-7-dev-centos

**Revised docker run command:**

docker run -d --name=marklogic10.0-7_local -p 7997-8012:7997-8012 -p 8014-8040:8014-8040 -p 8043:8013 -p 8090:8080 -p 9000:9000 marklogic-initial-install:10.0-7-dev-centos

**Note:** I originally had the same problem with port 8080 but mapped it to port 8090 which fixed the problem. Doing the same for port 8013 did not work.

Comment: please bring your docker compose for better helping

Comment: Do you need to map the ports to different ones? The script I use for creating new Docker containers with ML/DHF on it, which I do multiple times a day, starts with "docker run -d -it -p 8000-8030:8000-8030", and I've never run into issues with that.

Comment: All right - it seems that I need to use different steps for the installation. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the installation steps and not the ports.